# geocode my location and display with google-maps-for-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

i want to geocode my location and display with google-maps-for-rails gem

view:

```
= gmaps({ "map_options" => { "auto_adjust" => true } })
= form_tag geocode_geo_locations_path, :method => :get, :remote => true do
  = text_field_tag 'address'
  = submit_tag 'search'
```

in my controller i have:

```
def geocode
 @location = Gmaps4rails.geocode(params[:address])
 if @location
   @location_hash = @location.map { |loc| {:longitude => loc[:lng], :latitude => loc[:lat], :address => loc[:matched_address]} }.first 
 end
end
```

and in the view geocode.js.erb

```
Gmaps4Rails.replace_markers(<%=raw @location_hash.to_json %>);
```

it work so far, that i get a marker on the map, however the map doesnt get auto_adjusted .
how can i accomplish that??

Answer (score 1):

Ok... Indeed you just noticed a bug :)

Corrected now in 0.8.2.

Thanks!